# How to externally validate a logistic model by using external coefficients in R

Tags: r, validation, logistic-regression

I am trying to externally validate a logistic model using the published coefficients.
As an example, the model I would like help validating is:

```
glm(outcome ~ sex + age + sex:age, family = "binomial")
```

Where sex is a factor (e.g., M or F) and age is a continuos value.
The coefficients are:

```
Intercept: -2.827381;
M sex: 0.286466741;
Age: -0.036205346;
sex*age: -0.151205539.
```

The external validation dataset is a *mids* (mice) 100 imputations dataset called imputed_data_outcomes.
So what I was trying was:

```
model_linear_predictors <- expression(-2.827381 + (0.286466741*as.numeric(sex))+ (-0.036205346*age) + (-0.151205539*(as.numeric(sex)*age)))
linear_predictors <-with (imputed_data_outcomes, model_linear_predictors)
```

And then use these linear predictors to calculate the predicted probabilities on the external datasets etc.
However this step does not work, and I believe this is down to the wrong assignment of the sex*age coefficient, as it works fine if I remove the interaction term.

Could you please advise on the correct way of dealing with this? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emo. `with(data, expr,..)` and `within(data, expr,..)`are to use the expression on the data to do the calculation, in this case the predictions.

Note that `expr` needs to be defined using column names in `data`, see below for an example:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                  y=c(2, 2, 3, 4))
 
> with(df, x * y)
[1]  2  4  9 16
> within(df, z <-x * y)
  x y  z
1 1 2  2
2 2 2  4
3 3 3  9
4 4 4 16
```

In your case, you will need to use column names from `imputed_data_outcomes`, and write like

```
within(imputed_data_outcomes, prediction <- -2.827381 + (0.286466741*as.numeric(sex))+ (-0.036205346*age) + (-0.151205539*(as.numeric(sex)*age)))
```

Just make sure those column names are consistent.